# codeigniter pagination setup image?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have some problem someone please help me, I find in google how to solve this problem but cannot see, my problem is.

I have image at header, when I am at page one (pagination), the image still have, but when i go to next page (pagination) my image is gone, i think this is problem at link but i do not know how to handle it.

```
public function ListTender(){
    //pagination settings
    $config['base_url'] = site_url('tender/ListTender');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('tender');
    $config['per_page'] = "8";
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    $choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
    $config["num_links"] = floor($choice);
}
```

Comment: please show your code in view....

Comment: i think path to image is missing in next pagination section

Comment: yes the path is missing in next page and i got  the solution , the code for insert image in pagination must use base url  like this .                                                                 <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/img/Vnet.png"></img>